# Autoselect TextField text on focus

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to have a TextField where the entire text automatically gets selected when the user taps it (so they can replace it all without pressing delete).

Because `onFocusChanged` (and `onTextInputStarted`) are called before `onValueChange`, and `onValueChange` is always called on focus, I have to prevent running `onValueChange` once. Here's how I did it using a variable (`valueChangeLock`):

```kotlin
var value by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

// onValueChange is called after onFocusChanged, overriding the selection in onFocusChanged.
// Fix: Lock onValueChange when calling onFocusChanged
var valueChangeLock = false
BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = {
        if (valueChangeLock) {
            valueChangeLock = false
        } else {
            value = TextFieldValue(it.text, TextRange(it.text.length))
        }
    },
    modifier = modifier.onFocusChanged {
        if (it.isFocused) {
            valueChangeLock = true
            tfValue = TextFieldValue(value, TextRange(0, value.length))
        }
    },
)
```

Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Modifier.clickable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#clickable) interface to simplify this.

```
modifier = modifier.clickable {
    valueChangeLock = true
    tfValue = TextFieldValue(value, TextRange(0, value.length))
}
```

Also consider wrapping your text in a [SelectionContainer](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#select-text)